# install release version of app from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

I'm developing an iPhone app and my beta users (via Hockey) have reported some issues I can't reproduce.  I believe it is related to a difference in builds between what I get when I run on my device via xcode, and what the test users get from the archive package via hockey.  Is there some way I can get xcode to put the same version on my device that I release to the test users?

Comment: Why don't you install the app via Hockey too?

Comment: @lupz I can't, and I don't know why.  It gives a nondescript error which is the same as what would happen if the UUID wasn't in the provisioning profile (but that's not it).  Hockey support hasn't gotten back to me yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I figured it out... I guess it's just that I don't understand xcode very well.  The answer is to edit (or duplicate and then edit) the Scheme you're using to build the app.  This can be found on the product menu.  Set the "run" configuration to "release" and then do a clean build and run, and for me at least I was able to reproduce the issues the beta testers were seeing with the release archive.